# allow input to be 2.d.p, if not prompt error msg

Tags: input, python-3.x, numbers, decimal, python-3.3

I want to make sure that when the user inputs the exchange rate and amount, he can only input it to 2.d.p, if the input is not 2.d.p then there must be a error message. How can i do this without messing up my code?

Answer (score -1):

Check if the number rounded to 2 dp is the same number:

```
x = float(input(prompt))
if round(x, 2) != x:
    # x has more than 2 dp
```

Also, for money applications, consider using the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html) module - it works the same way:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal(input(prompt))
if round(x, 2) != x:
   # x has more than 2 dp
```

except that it avoids floating point representation issues, especially once you start doing arithmetic with the numbers.

Comment: but using both of those methods are messing up my current code, how do i add it in the code so it does not mess up my code?

Comment: How do you mean "messes up your code"? What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: What I mean is, I'm getting my code to do a float check.. how can I make it so that when I input something, python checks if it is a float and 2.d.p before moving on?

Comment: @ConfusedChild24 you do the two things separately. `input()`, convert to float (or Decimal, and handle the case that it doesn't parse), *then* check the number of dp, *then* move on.

Comment: -1: does not work for `0.1` as it is represented as ~0.10000000000000001

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk `round(0.1,2) == 0.1` is `True` for me in Python 2.7 and 3.3, but this type of potential error is *exactly* why my answer suggests using `Decimal`.